# Where to find latest bootstrap version theme?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, themes, twitter-bootstrap-3

At which website i will find latest Boot Strap V 3.x related free / paid themes? I searched on many sites but all have V 2.x related theme. I need nice admin panel theme.

Answer (score 1):

These here are also version 3 and are free - you may find them useful:

http://www.prepbootstrap.com/

Answer (score -1):

you can download bootstrapv3.0.0 from this site...

http://getbootstrap.com/

https://drupal.org/node/1840980

Answer (score -1):

You can find some in http://themeforest.net.

If you click this following link:
http://themeforest.net/search?term=admin%20bootstrap&category=site-templates&order_by=date

it will take you to the collection of admin theme, sorted from the newest (since bootstrap 3.0 is rather new) and specifically Twitter Bootstrap based.

These are not free, however they look very nice and modern. :)

You can check which version of bootstrap it is using from the result page too. You will find only handful of them using Bootstrap 3.0 for now.